# Overloading bottom menu keys

Tags: android

I'm making a toddler game and trying to prevent them from accessing the rest of the phone from within the app. I know you can overload the back key on the menu but how about the other 2 keys? I just want to add a confirmation screen that only adults can deal with so toddlers wont be able to mess with the phone and get out of the app.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can use something like "Kiosk mode" or at least part of it. Take a look here https://www.andreasschrade.com/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for ty so much

Comment: Great I will post my message as answer. Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you should use the "kiosk mode" features present on Android sdk. Take a look [here](https://www.andreasschrade.com/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/).